# How to edit main theme layout in wordpress?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I'm customizing a wordpress theme, I would like to remove some spaces added not by me, but I don't see in which part of my dashboard I can remove it.

First I want to edit the see more button language.
Second I want to remove the space or div is below the image.

Any suggestion?

[image]

This is a second image where I can show you the text editor.
Any suggestion?

[image]

Comment: You should edit the css associated with the theme

Answer (score 0):

For a quick fix, you can just go to Appearance -> Editor, then at the lowest part of the right side bar "Template", you should see the "Stylesheet" and go edit any "id" or "class" you want. e.g.

#more-site(for your button): margin-top: 10px;

Hope this helps.